# Modify standard report type - help with opportunity report

Tags: reporting, opportunity, administration, custom-report-type, report-builder

I would like to query all products and select multiple users from my opportunity teams but using salesforce's out of the box report **(Report Type: Opportunities with Opportunity Teams and Products)** I can only select one from each field and select either **OR** and not do an **AND** query.

[image]

Tried to also create a custom report type with opportunities and teams but the lookup user field doesn't have the 'lookup magnifying glass' to select multiple users when adding it to the filters section of the report page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a report with report type **"Opportunities with Opportunity Teams and Products"** for you desired results.

Instead you can try a **Joined Reports** with two report types - **Opportunity with Products** & **Opportunity with Opportunity Team Member**. In above both report types **Opportunity Name** is a common field, using that you can summarize the report and this way you can get all Opportunities with Team members and Products.

[image: It would look something like this]

Comment: Thanks! I am guessing this is the closest I can get to - that looks perfect but ideally want it to group by team member name and not by opportunity name - is that possible?

Comment: Am afraid its not possible to group it by team member
-> Products & Member not related to each other
-> There may exist one or more Member & one or more Products
-> So grouping by Team Member(which is not possible) would not give a clear picture as well.
-> But by Grouping with Opportunity Name you can get the Team Member Details & Products involved.

Please let me know if you got any other workaround for this scenario:-)